# .htaccess & mod_rewrite for passing GET parameters

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Currently I use this to pass GET parameters on an "elegant" way:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$                       index.php?module=$1                        [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$               index.php?module=$1&object=$2              [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$       index.php?module=$1&object=$2&submodule=$3 [L]
```

This works great for 3 parameters max., (and I'm sure it's *seriously* ugly).

Any way to do the same thing, for *n*-paremeters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use either:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ index.php?path=$1
```

or

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ index.php/$1
```

and tear apart `$_GET['path']` or `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` respectively.